# R switch() how to compare cases to a vector?

Tags: r, switch-statement

I've got a little issue with the switch statement in R.
The following code is OK ... :

```
    value = "B"
  switch(value, 
         "A"={
           print("value = A")
         },
         "B"={
           print("value = B")
         },
         "C"={
           print("value = C")
         },
         {
           print("Other !!!")
        }
        )
```

It returns :

```
[1] "value = B"
```

... but I would like to compare value to a vector's values like this :

```
mychr = c("A","B", "C")
  value = "B"
  switch(value, 
         mychr[1]={
           print(mychr[1])
         },
         mychr[2]={
           print(mychr[2])
         },
         mychr[3]={
           print(mychr[3])
         },
         {
           print("Other !!!")
         }
         )
```

And that doesn't work.

I can do this with "if else", or with the first code but I would like to understand the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Im sure there are easier ways but you can use `alist` and `do.call`

```
xlist = c("A","B", "C")
value = "B"
myList <- alist(print(xlist[1]), print(xlist[2]), print(xlist[3]), print("Other !!!"))
myList <- setNames(myList, c(xlist, ''))
do.call(switch, c(EXPR = value, myList))
```

Examples:

```
> value = "D"
> do.call(switch, c(EXPR = value, myList))
[1] "Other !!!"
> value = "A"
> do.call(switch, c(EXPR = value, myList))
[1] "A"
> value = "C"
> do.call(switch, c(EXPR = value, myList))
[1] "C"
> value = "B"
> do.call(switch, c(EXPR = value, myList))
[1] "B"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is that the `switch` alternatives require literal names and can't have a variable name. You're naming the arguments of the function and they internally become names of items in a list. In fact, the "" aren't necessary around your `A`, `B`, `C` in your first example. Knowing that, the problem becomes more obvious. Try assigning `b <- "B"` and then using `b` as the second switch item. That will fail as well because it's not going to resolve the variable name, just take it as a literal. In your case it fails with a syntax problem because `alist[1]` isn't a valid alternative label without quotes.

Similar restrictions are placed on switch statements in other languages as well. Think of the alternatives in the switch as being labelled like names of items in a `list` structure. They can be pretty much anything quoted but they don't need quotes and then there are restrictions on what they can be. What they *cannot* be is variable.

As you recognize in your question, there are alternative ways to do this. Here's a concise one that will be much faster than a `switch` statement (even if you did manage to solve the variable list items problem indirectly with a call function).

```
i <- which(alist == value)
if (length(i) == 1){
    print( paste0( 'value = ', alist[i]) )
}else {
    print( 'Other !!' ) }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator works on vectors, so what you need is just:

```
> a <- c("A", "B", "C")
> a
[1] "A" "B" "C"
> b <- "B"
> b == a
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Alternatively, you can use `which`

```
> which(a == b)
[1] 2
```

Note that can return several elements if `a` contains more than one instance of `b`

You can then proceed using an `if` or `ifelse` or `switch` statement on the result.

PS: you should avoid using `list` as a variable name, as it is a standard function in R

Answer (score 0):

Try using `vapply`.

i.e. in your case

```
vapply(mychr,switch,"",...SWITCH ARGS...)
```

I think what you would want is:

```
vapply(mychr,switch,"",
               mychr[1]=mychr[1],mychr[2]=mychr[2],mychr[3]=mychr[3],"Other !!!")
```